# c# visual studio allocate more memory

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, out-of-memory

Operating system: windows pro 64 bit.
Processor: intel i5 4460 3.2 GHZ 4CPU
visual studio 2015 i (I think 32 bit).
8 GB of RAM.

I have a code in c# which is supposed to take a lot of data from Excel, analyze it, and then put the output in Excel again.

I think that I have a problem with the memory. How can I allocate more memory to the program? I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

Here is a picture of the resource monitor and the task manager for the program "WindowsFormsApplication3".
[image]

The code stopped at the last command:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"" + filepath, ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Worksheet;
        Range rowdata = worksheet.Rows.Range["A2", converttrue2((arr.GetLength(1)-1).ToString())+(arr.GetLength(0)+1).ToString()];//THIS 1 ACTUALLY WORKS!
        rowdata.Value = arr;
```

The code works fine with smaller ranges and arrays.

I read that maybe I need to use visual studio 64 bit, will it help?

Comment: In Project Properties, target your solution to AnyCPU, and make sure "Prefer 32 bit" is turned OFF.

Comment: Its always best idea not to load huge amount of data if its not required..because at RAM is always limited... so i would also suggest that identify if there is anything which doesn't need to be in memory after its purpose is done. 64bit will help as well

Comment: The problem is in the code, not the memory. OOMs are raised when you use inefficient code and cause so much memory fragmentation that the runtime can't allocate the buffer you request. For example, lists have an internal buffer. Each time the list runs out of space, it allocates a new buffer with double the size and copies the old data. If you try to load 1M items one by one, you'll reallocate the buffer so many times that the runtime may not be able to find enough free space to go from 1M to 2M for that last item

Comment: That's why you should specify a *capacity* when you create a list. Even if you don't know how many items there are, guess. This will create an initial buffer large enough to hold the items specified in `capacity`. Furthermore, using Interop means you need to load Excel itself, thus wasting even more memory. Use a library like EPPlus to read, write Excel files directly.